# suma de datos de un 4 array sin repertir

Tags: java, java-8

buenas quiero sumar 4 datos si esta en el array  a b c d pero si ya sume una vez ya no volver a sumar mira en  a = 36 datos, b = 28, c=7, d=3; son las personas que tienen un monto; si sumo en una interacion y el codigo repite no debo sumar en otra interacion
 las iteraciones serian las siguientes

sumar un datos:
a+b+c+d
a+b+c
a+c+d
b+c+d
d+a+b
a+b
a+c
a+d
b+c
b+d
c+d
supongamos que tengo 5 empleados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
empleado 1 tendria q salir = 27
empleado 2 =4
empledo 3 = 21
Empleado 4 = 2
Empleado 5 = 1
pero me sale asi:
empleado 1 = 27
empleado1 = 21
empleado 1 =15
empleado 1 = 11
y asi quiero obviar si ya se sumo

```
for (int i = 0; i < list0706a.size(); i++) {

            double suma = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < list0706b.size(); j++) {
                if (list0706b.get(j).getCODIGO() == list0706a.get(i).getCODIGO()) {
                    for (int a = 0; a < list0706c.size(); a++) {
                        if (list0706c.get(a).getCODIGO() == list0706b.get(j).getCODIGO()) {
                            for (int d = 0; d < list0706d.size(); d++) {
                                if (list0706d.get(d).getCODIGO() == list0706c.get(a).getCODIGO()) {
                                    //Encontre =  1234;
                                    suma = (listh0706a.get(i).getRESULTADO()
                                            + listh0706b.get(j).getRESULTADO()
                                            + listh0706c.get(a).getRESULTADO()
                                            + listh0706d.get(d).getRESULTADO());
                                    pw.println(String.valueOf("0" + list0706d.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
                                            + "|" + list0706d.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|"
                                            + "0706" + "|"
                                            + df.format(suma) + "|"
                                            + df.format(suma) + "|"));
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

asi hice el for pero cuando continuo lo suma los anterioresja

Comment: podria colocar un ejemplo de salida o resultado que esperas con los datos que menciona

Comment: me voy al punto debajo de la imagen

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que el código es muy confuso. Lo segundo es que, a menos que exista algo que no sepa o vea, este código es extremadamente ineficiente.

Veo que estas empleando 4 listas de un objeto con dos atributos ( **codigo** y **resultado**)
Estas listas se llaman:

- list0706a
- list0706b
- list0706c
- list0706d

---

**Si las listas están ordenadas** ( el primer registro en todas las listas pertenecen al mismo empleado, el segundo al segundo, etc y luego el tamaño de todas las listas son del mismo tamaño)

puedes solucionarlo con un simple bucle

```
for (int i = 0; i < list0706a.size(); i++) {
  suma = (listh0706a.get(i).getRESULTADO()
         + listh0706b.get(i).getRESULTADO()
         + listh0706c.get(i).getRESULTADO()
         + listh0706d.get(i).getRESULTADO());
  pw.println(String.valueOf("0" + list0706d.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
             + "|" + list0706d.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|"
             + "0706" + "|"
             + df.format(suma) + "|"
             + df.format(suma) + "|"));
}
```

y así pasas de un código de coste n^4 a coste n.

---

**Si las listas están desordenadas** optaria por un hashmap (cambia employee por tu objeto)

```
  Map<Employee, Integer> map = new HashMap<Employee, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<list0706a.size();i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(list0706a.get(i)))
        {
            map.put(list0706a.get(i),map.get(list0706a.get(i)+list0706a.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(list0706a.get(i),map.get(list0706a.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list0706b.size();i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(list0706b.get(i)))
        {
            map.put(list0706b.get(i),map.get(list0706b.get(i)+list0706b.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(list0706b.get(i),map.get(list0706b.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list0706c.size();i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(list0706c.get(i)))
        {
            map.put(list0706c.get(i),map.get(list0706c.get(i)+list0706c.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(list0706c.get(i),map.get(list0706c.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list0706d.size();i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(list0706d.get(i)))
        {
            map.put(list0706d.get(i),map.get(list0706d.get(i)+list0706d.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(list0706d.get(i),map.get(list0706d.get(i).getRESULTADO()));
        }
    }

    for(PlayerModel i=0:map.keySet())
    {
        pw.println(String.valueOf("0" + i.getCODIGO_DOC()
                + "|" + i.getCEDULA() + "|"
                + "0706" + "|"
                + df.format(map.get(i)) + "|"
                + df.format(map.get(i)) + "|"));
    }
}
```

Y aun así este codigo no me gusta nada ya que ademas de que es costoso de comprender, su coste es de 5N

---

Recomiendo que encuentres, si es posible, alguna forma de que no recibieses 4 listas distintas. Planteate al objeto employee ( o como se llame) añadirle parametros por cada valor posible que puede tener o cambiar getRESULTADO para que devuelva una lista de entero/doubles